# Saving a decision tree model for later application in Julia

Tags: export, julia, decision-tree

I have trained a pruned decision tree model in Julia using the DecisionTree module. I now want to save this model for use on other data sets later.

I have tried converting the model to a data array for export using writetable() and I have tried exporting using writedlm() and neither of these work. When I look at the type of the model I see that it is a DecisionTree.Node type. I don't know how to work with this and can't get it to export/save.

```
In:DataFrame(PrunedModel)
Out:LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{DataFrames.DataFrame}, ::DecisionTree.Node)
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor DataFrames.DataFrame(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert(::Type{DataFrames.DataFrame}, !Matched::Array{T,2})
  convert(::Type{DataFrames.DataFrame}, !Matched::Dict{K,V})
  ...
while loading In[22], in expression starting on line 1 
 in call at essentials.jl:56

In:typeof(PrunedModel)
Out:DecisionTree.Node
```

Any ideas how I can get this model saved for use later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly that this is a Julia object, you should try using the JLD.jl package to save the object to disk and load it back in, preserving the type information.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. When I then imported the saved .jld file into a new session I had to first type using DecisionTree so that the session could understand the structure of the data that was being imported but after doing that and using JLD it worked perfectly.